# Polar plot direction with increase in frequency

Tags: control-engineering

If the angle corresponding to the open loop transfer function of a system at infinite frequency is smaller than that at zero frequency, the polar plot curve in the clockwise direction with increase in frequency. Why is it so ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is just how the phase component of of a complex value, returned by the transfer function, is defined. Phase is the angle between the positive real axis and the complex value in the counterclockwise direction.

So if you start at some phase $\phi_1$ at a frequency of zero and go to phase $\phi_2$ at an infinite frequency, where $\phi_1>\phi_2$, then on average the polar plot should rotate in the clockwise direction (the direction in which the phase decreases).

Comment: But why shouldn't have the curve crossed the 0° or 360° before reaching infinite frequency

Comment: @TVV For the inequality I assumed that the phase is continues and thus will not have made jumps of 360°, because otherwise it would be impossible to proof.